# How to link saml service provider(addRPServiceProvider) and application in WSO2 IS?

Tags: soap, openid, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

Created an application with this soap call createApplication()

```
    <soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"         
    xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://model.common.application.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <xsd:createApplication>
     <xsd:serviceProvider>
        <xsd1:applicationName>travelocity.com</xsd1:applicationName>
        <xsd1:description>SaMLApp</xsd1:description>
     </xsd:serviceProvider>
  </xsd:createApplication>
```

Added a service provider with this soap call addRPServiceProvider()

```
   <soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" 
    xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.saml.sso.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <xsd:addRPServiceProvider>
     <xsd:spDto><xsd1:assertionConsumerUrl>http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/home.jsp</xsd1:assertionConsumerUrl>
        <xsd1:doSignAssertions>true</xsd1:doSignAssertions>
        <xsd1:doSignResponse>true</xsd1:doSignResponse>
        <xsd1:doSingleLogout>true</xsd1:doSingleLogout>
        <xsd1:issuer>sophos.com</xsd1:issuer>         
        <xsd1:nameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</xsd1:nameIDFormat>
        <xsd1:useFullyQualifiedUsername>true</xsd1:useFullyQualifiedUsername>
     </xsd:spDto>
  </xsd:addRPServiceProvider>
```

Now how should I link those by calling updateApplication()? What should be the attributes of update application soap call? I referred [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Service+Provider+Configurations+used+with+APIs#ServiceProviderConfigurationsusedwithAPIs-ConfiguringSAML2webSSO), but could not figure out the linking part in updateApplication().

Note: I can create these on WSO2 IS management console web UI. I could not create them through API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAML application will be added as an inbound authentication configuration of the Service Provider. So when you call `updateApplication` method, use the issuer name that you used to create the SAML application (travelocity.com in your case) as the `inboundAuthKey` in `inboundAuthenticationConfig` section. If you need a code sample please follow [this](https://github.com/JKAUSHALYA/sp-migration-client).